# Are their any Christian denominations that reject the teachings of Paul?

Tags: denomination-survey, paul-apostle, canon

I am a Yeshua following zealot. I love the Lord as much as life itself as it is granted through the Father's word which is our savior himself. I am pretty well educated in Bible/church history and am always seeking more knowledge. Through prayerful guidance through the word I found that the spirit of the Pauline writings didn't sit well with the spirit of the other texts and gospels, to me at least it seems because somehow Paul has been elevated beyond everyone else in Christianity it seem.

So my question is this, do any Christian denominations teach the word without the books attributed to Paul?

Comment: Voted back up to '0'.  Even if the question is unpopular, or the suggestions as part of it might be dangerous, trying to have it removed is not the answer. What is? Reasoning based on the Scriptures is what can overturn "reasonings and every lofty thing raised up against the knowledge of God" (2 Corinthians 10:4,5). Such an approach is not popular with everyone here, but this is how it's done properly (some make a point of ignoring the Scriptures in favour of traditions, and "Church" documents made up by apparently popular individuals who turned up once the apostles were no longer there).

Comment: @Mr. Donutz I'm not sure I follow your answer. You quote a verse from Pauline Scripture then make the point of "Church documents from popular individuals after the apostles. The only people to call Paul a apostles is Paul, his scribe, Luke and Barnabus.

Comment: Thank you, Nigel.  I will remove my comments.

Comment: I did close my post because the question has been answered elsewhere. Nigel, the millions, no billions that raise him up is not surprising. “Enter through the narrow gate; for the gate is wide and the road is easy that leads to destruction, and there are many who take it. 14 For the gate is narrow and the road is hard that leads to life, and there are few who find it. ~ Matthew 7:13-14 Remember the devil deceived the whole world so much so that he would deceive even the very elect if it were so possible. Do you believe the 2.2 Billion Christians of the world are the few who find it?

Comment: @JasonHenley I was only referring to the vast numbers who accept that Paul is an apostle. Which is a start. If an apostle is rejected, then one will not even find the gate, never mind get inside it.

Comment: Is that a verse? Honestly asking. Paul has mocked the apostles multiple times in Scripture referring to them condescendingly as "Super Apostles" publicly berated Peter and spoke of it with pride and ego. He seemed invious of them and was extremely concerned about his own greatness as to stand above them.